# php artisan db:seed of Laravel5 is not working

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

php artisan db:seed of Laravel5 is not working when I am trying to use it. My **DatabaseSeeder.php** class is as below

```
    <?php

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder 
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    }
}



class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
  public function run()
  {
    DB::table('users')->delete();

    User::create(array(
        'name'     => 'Rakesh',
        'username' => 'Rakesh',
        'email'    => 'sharmarakesh395@gmail.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('mypass'),
    ));
  }
}
```

I am trying to run `php artisan db:seed`. But it is not working. Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error messages or what do you mean when saying "not working"?

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` first